# Curve fitting a percentage of data

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting

I have two sets of real data, xdata and ydata, and I'm trying to do an exponencial fitting to them, as shown in my code below.

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, color='r', label="Demanda máxima", alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r--')
```

The fitting is working fine, however, I need 90% of my data points to be under/over my fitted curve. Is that a way to do this?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit the curve using subset of the data:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
ydata = (10 + np.random.randn(100)) * np.exp(-xdata ) + (3 + np.random.randn(100))
idx = list(range(len(xdata)))
np.random.shuffle(idx)
lim = int(0.9 * len(idx))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata[idx[:lim]], ydata[idx[:lim]])
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, color='r', label="Demanda máxima", alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r--')
plt.show()
```

**Update**
I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you have a perfect fit and all you need is to add some noise, just add noise on the y-data, ie:

```
std = 1
ydata = ydata + std * np.random.randn(ydata.shape)
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I'll try this alternative. Thanks :)